# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator via Separation of Variables and/or Normalization

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hermite-polynomials

I tried to solve the problem of the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator in one dimension.
$$\frac{-\hbar ^2}{2m} \Psi _{xx} + \frac{1}{2}m(\omega x)^2\Psi = i\hbar \Psi _t$$
I set up the following condition: let 
$$\Psi = e^{-\beta t}u$$
Thus, 
$$\Psi_{xx} = e^{-\beta t}u_{xx}$$
and 
$$\Psi_t = e^{-\beta t}u_t-\beta e^{-\beta t}u$$
I plug this into the Schrodinger PDE formula to get, 
$$\frac{-\hbar ^2}{2m} e^{-\beta t}u_{xx} + \frac{1}{2}m(\omega x)^2e^{-\beta t}u = i\hbar e^{-\beta t}u_t-\beta e^{-\beta t}u$$
I add one more condition(I am not entirely sure if this condition is valid but I assume it is), 
$$\frac{-\hbar ^2}{2m} u _{xx} - i\hbar u _t = 0$$
I set up this condition mainly because this equation is very easy to solve. (then again maybe my error is here and requires the boundary conditions at $\pm \infty$ to approach 0.
Factoring out the common term on the substituted equation results in, 
$$\frac{-\hbar ^2}{2m} u_{xx}-i\hbar u_t + \frac{1}{2}m(\omega x)^2u = -i\hbar\beta u$$
Using the second condition listed above, the result is, 
$$\frac{1}{2}m(\omega x)^2u = -i\hbar\beta u$$
And thus 
$$\beta = \frac{i}{2\hbar }m(\omega x)^2$$
Thus my solution is, 
$$\Psi = e^{-\frac{i}{2\hbar }m(\omega x)^2t}u$$
Is this a practical approach for solving QHO problem? How should I normalize from here so that I end up with the Hermite Polynomials? By the way I expect to solve $u$ with Separation of Variables.

Comment: I recall the standard technique being to use a power series to derive a two-term recursion relation. The idea is that for the solution to be physical, the series must be finite, so you find that the condition for it to be normalizeable  requires a recursion relation. http://physics.gmu.edu/~dmaria/590%20Web%20Page/public_html/qm_topics/harmonic/

Comment: A problem that jumps out at me is you assume $\beta$ is independent of $x$ as you write "$\Psi_{xx} = e^{-\beta t}u_{xx}$", but later deduce that "$\beta = \frac{i}{2h}m(\omega x)^2$". This seems to be inconsistent

Comment: Okay I see so that assumption really cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to separate

$$
\Psi(t, x) = \color{blue}{e^{-\beta t}}\color{red}{u(x)} \tag{1}
$$

where $\beta$ is a *constant*. With this in mind, Schrodinger's equation becomes

$$
\color{blue}{e^{-\beta t}}\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{{\rm d}^2 \color{red}{u}}{{\rm d}x^2} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2 \color{red}{u}\right] = \color{red}{u}\left[i\hbar \frac{{\rm d}\color{blue}{e^{-\beta t}}}{{\rm d}t} \right]
$$

Or rearranging a bit

$$
\frac{1}{\color{red}{u}}\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{{\rm d}^2 \color{red}{u}}{{\rm d}x^2} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2 \color{red}{u}\right] = -i\hbar \beta  \tag{2}
$$

which is just an ordinary equation, and can be solved via Hermite polynomials. It is customary to write

$$
\beta = -i \frac{E}{\hbar} \tag{3}
$$

where $E$ is the energy of the system.